# What database is most efficient for simple group by queries on tons of data?

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, group-by, nosql

For each account, I have millions of data items (rows in analytics logs), each with 20-50 numeric properties (they can be null too). I need to show them stats which mostly involve queries like `SELECT SUM(f1), f2, f3 WHERE f4>f5 GROUP BY f2, f3`. The aggregation functions are sometimes more complex than SUM(), and GROUP BY sometimes involves simple functions like ROUND(). The problem is that such queries are built in the user interface and can be run on any combination of those properties (though there are some popular combinations of course).

Once in the database, the data would most likely not be modified, only read. It should be possible to easily add/remove properties – not necessarily realtime in database terms, but it should not require complete table blocks like in MySQL.

What SQL or NoSQL databases would be best to handle these kinds of queries? I was thinking of PostgreSQL or MongoDB, even though in the latter I will most likely have to use MapReduce rather than its Group feature because of its limitations.

Any other advice on performance of such queries? Does this sound possible to do at all, or do I absolutely have to ask users to pre-define which exact queries they want to run?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What query performance are you looking for?  How often will it be queried?

If you're OK with query performance in the low minutes and have a similarly low query rate, then you can use a relational table with a main table for the data items, and a join table for the properties.  Be sure to put a combined index on the second table on the combination (property_type, data_item_id, property_value) to guarantee good query performance.  You don't actually need property_value in there, but if you have it then queries can pull their data from the index in a highly efficient manner, which will make joins much, much easier.  You can do this with any relational database.  I happen to like PostgreSQL, but MySQL can also work.  (But less efficiently on complex queries.)

If you follow this strategy then each property you want will require you to add yet another join.  But the joins will be fairly efficient.

Comment: Thanks, @peter! I was looking for subminute times for random unoptimized queries, so that could work. I don't actually have any payload on data items except their properties, so do I really need a separate table for data items? I thought I could make queries on just one properties table roughly like that: http://pastie.org/1587684 Is that approximately how you meant it?

Comment: Don't you have a date on the log rows?  And perhaps a filename?  This metadata makes sense to have in its own row.  If you don't want that metadata, you could technically do something like what you suggest, but I would recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

You can build this kind of application in an RDBMS or in a NoSQL database ([Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo) for example, has both a key-value pair API and a SQL API). The key-value pair API is a nice option, since it supports some pretty low level optimizations that may help when looking at how to tune the performance to meet your application needs.

Another option is to look into a columnar data store, but even that kind of product is going to have to retrieve data from multiple columns (which is slow in these kinds of databases) in order to resolve the kinds of queries that you list.

Ultimately the issue here boils down to disk I/O VS cache and data organization. The more data that you can fit into memory, the less I/O you have to perform and I/O is going to be the performance killer. The more compact you can make the data, the more rows will fit in the memory that you have. I would suggest looking into Berkeley DB, especially the key-value pair API. You can then choose to create one or more tables with the properties organized in an manner that optimizes the most frequent kinds of access. Additionally, if you're using the key-value pair API, take a look at the Bulk Get functions -- this allows you to fetch and process whole groups of records at a time.

You may also want to create and maintain some "well known" statistical results (in memory and/or persisted on disk) that allow you to take "shortcuts" when the user is asking for a value that has already been computed.

Good luck in your research.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described - essentially ad hoc aggregate queries on data that does not need to be realtime - is what OLAP solutions are very good at. In addition to other suggestions you've seen, you should look into whether an OLAP solution makes sense for you.

Comment: So I've tried several schemes already on a plain PostgreSQL, and the best performance came from having (rolap-style) separate tables for each property and one table with events and their metadata. An aggregation query involving a couple properties and event time takes just like 5 seconds if there are a million events, and scales nicely. I didn't even tune anything yet, cool! Thanks!